# SessionRenderer not rendering throws ViewExpiredException

Tags: icefaces

8.2 with Seam and JSF 1.2 . My problem is having a method in my backing bean in which I am initializing certain values before the page is presented to the user. Here in the backing bean method, I have used SessionRenderer.addCurrentSession("all").

In my page, after a user selects a drop down in the page, I am partially submitting the page to a valueChangeListener method defined in the same backing bean. After manipulating the values there, I am trying to render the view from the change listener method by using SessionRenderer.render("all").

This is the place where i get the ViewExpiredException: Execute push on unknown view.

Also the server logs shows that [ViewStateManagerImpl] Missing View Root in Restore state in ice session [session id] view number: 1

Please help me in solving this !!

my faces-config.xml looks like

```
<managed-bean-name>renderMgr</managed-bean-name> 

<managed-bean-class> 

    com.icesoft.faces.async.render.RenderManager

</managed-bean-class> 

<managed-bean-scope>application</managed-bean-scope>
```

```
<managed-bean-name>RulesBean</managed-bean-name> 

<managed-bean-class>

    com.xxxx.rpa.session

</managed-bean-class> 

<managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope> 

<managed-property> 

    <property-name>renderManager</property-name> 

    <value>#{renderMgr}</value> 

</managed-property>
```

In my web.xml i have set the context-param

```
    <param-name>com.icesoft.faces.synchronousUpdate</param-name>

    <param-value>false</param-value>
```

```
    <param-name>com.icesoft.faces.concurrentDOMViews</param-name> 

    <param-value>true</param-value>
```